# Objects falling through the ground plane in cannon.js and three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, physics-engine, cannon.js

I recently started working with physics engines. I am using `cannon-es.js` with `three.js`.

The box and the loaded model are just passing through the plane and falling out of view. I tried using `groundBody.quaternion.setFromEuler(-Math.PI/2,0,0)` but the objects were moving up the screen instead of down. I think positioning and dimensions are the issues here. Can someone please help me out? Thank you so much!

Here is the code I am working on:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My 3D Model</title>
    <script type="module">
        import * as THREE from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/build/three.module.js";
        import { GUI } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/dat.gui@0.7.7/build/dat.gui.module.js";
        import { TrackballControls } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/TrackballControls.js";
        import {OrbitControls} from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js";
        import { STLLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/STLLoader.js";
        import { OBJLoader } from "https://cdn.skypack.dev/three@0.136.0/examples/jsm/loaders/OBJLoader.js";
        import * as CANNON from 'https://unpkg.com/cannon-es@0.19.0/dist/cannon-es.js'

        // webgl 
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

        renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);

        document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
       // scene
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(
            75,
            window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight,
            0.1,
            1000
        );

        const orbit = new OrbitControls(camera,renderer.domElement);
       

        camera.position.set(0,200,-100);
        orbit.update();
        const ambientLight = new THREE.AmbientLight();
       scene.add( ambientLight );

       const directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 5.0 );
       directionalLight.position.set( 10, 100, -100 );
       scene.add( directionalLight );
        
        
        const world = new CANNON.World({
          gravity : new CANNON.Vec3(0,-9.81,0)
        });

        const groundBody = new CANNON.Body({
            shape : new CANNON.Plane(),
            type : CANNON.Body.STATIC,
        })
        world.addBody(groundBody);
        groundBody.quaternion.setFromEuler(Math.PI/2,0,0);
        let mesh,body;
        const material = new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ color: 0xaaaaaa })
       const loader = new OBJLoader()
       loader.load('resources/Model_8_8.obj', (object) => {
        const geometry = object.children[0].geometry;
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material)
       scene.add(mesh)
       //mesh.rotateZ(Math.PI);
       const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
            const width = boundingBox.max.x - boundingBox.min.x;
            const height = boundingBox.max.y - boundingBox.min.y;
            const depth = boundingBox.max.z - boundingBox.min.z;
            const shape = new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(width / 2, height / 2, depth / 2))
            body= new CANNON.Body({
              mass :10,
              shape :shape
            })
            //body3.position.set(0, 1800, -100);
            world.addBody(body);
            const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(30,30,30);
        const boxMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color: 0x00ff00,
            wireframe : true
        });
            const boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry,boxMat);
            scene.add(boxMesh);

        const groundGeo = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(300,300);
        const groundMat = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
            color:0xffffff,
            side : THREE.DoubleSide,
            wireframe: true
        });
        const groundMesh = new THREE.Mesh(groundGeo,groundMat);
        scene.add(groundMesh);
       

        const boxBody = new CANNON.Body({
            mass : 10,
            shape : new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(15,15,15))
        });
        world.addBody(boxBody);
    
        const timeStep = 1 / 60 ;

        function animate(){
            world.step(timeStep);
            groundMesh.position.copy(groundBody.position);
            groundMesh.quaternion.copy(groundBody.quaternion);
            boxMesh.position.copy(boxBody.position);
            boxMesh.quaternion.copy(boxBody.quaternion);
            mesh.position.copy(body.position);
            mesh.quaternion.copy(body.quaternion);

            renderer.render(scene,camera);
        }
        renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
        window.addEventListener('resize',function(){
            camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
            camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
            renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth,window.innerHeight);
        });
      })
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

### finally

the shortest solution is to use **negative** rotation **groundBody.quaternion.setFromEuler(-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0)**
and set the position from your **boxBody.position.y = 100**;

=> but i dont know if this the right way to do this and i don't know why that works and the other way not xD

other solutions below.

---

im not familiar with cannonJS but it seems there are 2 options that it works.
like in https://github.com/schteppe/cannon.js?files=1 where gravity is set to Z coordinate , change the gravity to Z coordinate and dont do the rotate with the plane. Then give a position for the  boxBody.position.z = 100 and it works.

Otherwise you have to change your size of your plane geometry, do instead the new CANNON.Plane() shape, a new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(15, 15, 1)) shape, while the Z coordination is only 1, after rotating this is your Y size. In this case set the position not in z but in y (boxBody.position.y = 100). The Mistake in your example, i think, is that both physics are together in each of them, what creates a failure.
( i dont know really what new Cannon.Plane() is doing. ) **cheers**

some code snippets that should work:

```
  const groundBody = new CANNON.Body({
    shape: new CANNON.Box(new CANNON.Vec3(15, 15, 1)),
    type: CANNON.Body.STATIC,
  });

  world.addBody(boxBody);
  boxBody.position.y = 100;
```

**additional**
your plane is static, so you dont have to update your position all the time in the animation loop. I tried with the example from https://sbcode.net/threejs/physics-cannonjs/ and do this and it works also.

```
const planeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(25, 25);
const planeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    planeGeometry,
    new THREE.MeshPhysicalMaterial({ color: "white" })
);
planeMesh.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
planeMesh.receiveShadow = true;
scene.add(planeMesh);
const planeShape = new CANNON.Plane();
const planeBody = new CANNON.Body({ mass: 0 });
planeBody.addShape(planeShape);
planeBody.quaternion.setFromAxisAngle(
    new CANNON.Vec3(1, 0, 0),
    -Math.PI / 2
  );
  world.addBody(planeBody);
```

> important to set the position of your boxBody.position on start to prevent that the box is in the ground plane at beginning, otherwise the boxBody get a lot of velocity.

---

**or at least with your code template**

1. add boxBody.position.y = 100
2. do not rotate your groundBody
3. rotate your groundMesh as you want groundMesh.rotateX(-Math.PI / 2);
4. give the rotation to your groundBody groundBody.quaternion.copy(groundMesh.quaternion).

i dont know what was really the fault, maybee its not so easy to rotate the body of cannon, instead add the quaternion of the mesh after rotate. remember do not do a world step update before you have the correct start position of the objects. So the groundBody.quaternion.copy(groundMesh.quaternion) must come before the world.step().

Comment: Thank you so much . The box is fixed. However I am still not able to make the model interact with the ground. Can you please suggest something for that?

Comment: it depends on your object i think. Maybee its a group instead of a Mesh,  try to set the boundingBox from the mesh which you was generated or from the children of your loaded object.

const boundingBox = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(mesh)